# Sharing iSCSI from one NIC to another on same machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, iscsi, network-attached-storage

I have a Windows 2008 system with 2 NICs. One NIC is connected directly to an NAS (NIC1), and the other NIC is connected to the general network (NIC2). I am trying to share a iSCSI connection from the NAS (NIC1) with the general network (NIC2).

The reason I'm doing this is to ensure that the only way to administer the NAS would be through this system which has 2 factor authentication enabled on it. The NAS does not allow 2 factor authentication which is required in our business.

Comment: I guess you'd have to enable RRAS on this system and configure it for LAN routing so that it can route traffic between the two networks, but I don't think that's going to work with your 2FA. How would your 2FA authenticate this traffic? Routing is a Layer 3 component, 2FA is a Layer 7 component. Why don't you just connect to this system directly when you want to connect to the NAS?

Comment: So the only way to get into the administration console for the NAS is through the system with the 2 NICs, and this system (we'll call it a jump server) has duo 2fa on remote desktop. The NAS doesn't support 2fa unfortunately.

One problem I'm running into is that when I do a `ipconfig /all` on the jump server, the NAS is assigned an IP address that goes back to localhost (I assume it's localhost because it goes back to the IIS7 homepage.